# Lua 5.2 C API and require

Tags: c, lua, yaml

## Issue

I want to call a Lua script which `require()`s `lyaml` module, Lua binding for LibYAML, from a C program.

I compiled Lua 5.2 from source and I hacked the module to make it work with Lua 5.2. It can be found on [github](https://github.com/crohn/yaml).

The Lua script follows, it works either with Lua 5.1 and 5.2:

```
-- foo.lua
require('lyaml')

function hello ()
  res = lyaml.load("a: 4\n")
  return res.a
end

-- then calling hello() it works like a charm
print( hello() ) -> 4
```

### Problem

I wrote a C program which should call `hello()` from the script, following [Programming in Lua, Chapter 25](http://www.lua.org/pil/25.html) and [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html).

The C program follows:

```
/* foo.c */
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  double z;

  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  if (luaL_dofile(L, "foo.lua"))
    luaL_error(L, "error running script: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));

  lua_getglobal(L, "hello");

  if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0) != 0)
    luaL_error(L, "error calling hello: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));

  if (!lua_isnumber(L, -1))
    luaL_error(L, "result must be number");        

  z = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
  lua_pop(L, 1);

  lua_close(L);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile issuing:

```
gcc -Wall -o foo foo.c -ldl -lm -llua
```

Then when running `foo`, I receive at runtime the following error:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call tu Lua API (
    error running script: error loading module 'lyaml' from file '/path/to/lyaml.so':
       /path/to/lyaml.so: undefined symbol: lua_gettop)
Aborted
```

So I tried to load `lyaml` from the C program, adding the following line after `luaL_openlibs()` call:

```
luaL_requiref(L, "lyaml", luaopen_package, 1);
```

After recompilation the error becomes:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call tu Lua API (
    error running script: 
       hello.lua:4: attempt to index global 'lyaml' (a nil value))
Aborted
```

So I imagine that there's no `lyaml` symbol and the `require()` call fails somehow.

By reading `luaL_requiref()` documentation I thought `modname` would be set by its call setting `glb` flag to true:

```
void luaL_requiref (lua_State *L, const char *modname, 
                    lua_CFunction openf, int glb);
```

> Calls function `openf` with string `modname` as an argument and sets the call result in `package.loaded[modname]`, as if that function has been called through `require`.
>   If glb is true, also stores the result into global `modname`.
>   Leaves a copy of that result on the stack.

I tried to comment the `require()` call in Lua script and the result is the same.

### Question

What did I do wrong? Am I forgetting to do something?

---

#### EDIT

I hacked the module updating deprecated (removed) functions/types with their substitute as follows:

```
lua_strlen() -> luaL_len()
luaL_reg     -> luaL_Reg
luaL_getn()  -> luaL_len()
```

However Lua scripts using `lyaml` work so I think the problem is not my hack.

I tried original `lyaml` module with Lua 5.1. Results are the same, so I'm sure the problem is not my hack.

#### UPDATE

Adding the following line, as suggested by Doug Currie in his answer, the C program works perfectly with Lua 5.1. I still get the same error in 5.2 though.

```
lyaml = require('lyaml')
```

Comment: "I hacked the module to make it work with Lua 5.2." Did you "hack" it *correctly*? If you're not using the original module, then there's no way to know that it works correctly without seeing your actual code. Also, what does Luabind have to do with this? Does `lyaml` use that?

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry for [luabind] I did not mention to use it. I added further explanation about the hack.

Comment: @NicolBolas As I reported in the update, I ran the same scenario with Lua 5.1 and the original `lyaml` module. Results are the same. I would say that it would be good practice, and matter of respect, to ask further information about issues before voting close. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo.lua` as written will only run in Lua 5.1.x -- your hacked `lyaml.c` doesn't set the global `lyaml` and neither does require in Lua 5.2. I suspect your PATH did not have Lua 5.2 when you ran the first test "works like a charm," or else you set `lyaml` manually before you loaded `foo.lua`.

`foo.lua` should start with

```
lyaml = require('lyaml')
```

Comment: `foo.lua` works either with Lua 5.1 and 5.2. I can even `require('lyaml')` and work interactively with the module in both versions. The problem shows up when I try to call `hello()` from the C program. How do I set the global `lyaml`? I tried using `luaL_requiref()`, as written, without success. Thanks.

Comment: See my addendum on a 5.1 and 5.2 compatible approach as long as `lyaml.so`'s `luaopen_lyaml` returns the module table, which it appears to do correctly in the git repo.

Comment: Adding `lyaml = require('yaml')` makes the C program work with 5.1! In 5.2 returns the same error... can't understand why. Lua  is compiled with `-DLUA_COMPAT_ALL`, as default.

Answer (score 7):

I solved... the root of all problems was a bad use of `luaL_requiref()`.

Reading [this thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-07/msg00100.html) i got inspired by this follow up:

> In Lua 5.2, libraries no longer create globals; they just return
>   the library table. 
>  `luaL_openlibs` calls `luaL_requiref` instead of calling `luaopen_*`, and `luaL_requiref` sets the corresponding globals.

so it is necessary to call `luaL_requiref()` to load the module and set the `lyaml` global.

As stated in the question I tried using

```
luaL_requiref(L, "lyaml", luaopen_package, 1);
```

but it's totally wrong because `luaopen_package()` is the loader function for Lua standard `package` module... I had to use instead:

```
luaL_requiref(L, "lyaml", luaopen_lyaml, 1);
```

and compile with

```
gcc -L/path/to/5.2 -Wall -o foo foo.c -ldl -lm -llua -l:lyaml.so.1
```

to get references to `luaopen_lyaml()`.

---

In Lua 5.1, as Doug Currie said, it was enough to issue

```
lyaml = require('lyaml')
```

in `hello.lua`, without calling `luaL_requiref()` in C program.